# Azure Postgres AUTOVACUM AND ANALYZE THRESHOLD - How to change it?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, azure-postgresql, autovacuum, table-statistics

I am coming again with another Postgres question. We are using the Managed Service from Azure that uses `autovacuum`. Both `vacuum` and `statistics` are automatic.

The problem I am getting is that for a specific query, when it is running at specific hours, the plan is not good. I realized that after collecting statistics manually, the plan behaves better back again.

From the documentation of Azure I got the following:

> The vacuum process reads physical pages and checks for dead tuples.
> Every page in shared_buffers is considered to have a cost of 1
> (vacuum_cost_page_hit). All other pages are considered to have a cost
> of 20 (vacuum_cost_page_dirty), if dead tuples exist, or 10
> (vacuum_cost_page_miss), if no dead tuples exist. The vacuum operation
> stops when the process exceeds the autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit.
>
> After the limit is reached, the process sleeps for the duration
> specified by the autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay parameter before it
> starts again. If the limit isn't reached, autovacuum starts after the
> value specified by the autovacuum_naptime parameter.
>
> In summary, the autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay and
> autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit parameters control how much data cleanup
> is allowed per unit of time. Note that the default values are too low
> for most pricing tiers. The optimal values for these parameters are
> pricing tier-dependent and should be configured accordingly.
>
> The autovacuum_max_workers parameter determines the maximum number of
> autovacuum processes that can run simultaneously.
>
> With PostgreSQL, you can set these parameters at the table level or
> instance level. Today, you can set these parameters at the table level
> only in Azure Database for PostgreSQL.

Let's imagine that I want to stress the default values I have for specific tables, as currently all of them are using the default ones for the whole database.

[image]

Keeping in mind that, I could try to use ( where `X` is what I don't know )

```
ALTER TABLE tablename SET (autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = X );
ALTER TABLE tablename SET (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = X);
ALTER TABLE tablename SET (autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = X );
ALTER TABLE tablename SET (autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = X );
```

Currently I have these values in `pg_stat_all_tables`

```
SELECT schemaname,relname,n_tup_ins,n_tup_upd,n_tup_del,last_analyze,last_autovacuum,last_autoanalyze,analyze_count,autoanalyze_count 
FROM pg_stat_all_tables where schemaname = 'swp_am_hcbe_pro' 
and relname in ( 'submissions','applications' ) 

"swp_am_hcbe_pro"   "applications"  "264615"    "11688533"  "18278" "2021-11-11 08:45:45.878654+00" "2021-11-11 13:50:27.498745+00" "2021-11-10 12:02:04.690082+00" "1" "152"
"swp_am_hcbe_pro"   "submissions"   "663107"    "687757"    "51603" "2021-11-11 08:46:48.054731+00" "2021-11-07 04:41:30.205468+00" "2021-11-04 15:25:45.758618+00" "1" "20"
```

[image]

Those two tables are by far the ones getting most of the DML activity.

**Questions**

- How can I determine which values for those specific parameters of the auto_vacuum are the best for tables with huge dml activity ?
- How can I force Postgres to run more times the automatic analyze for these tables that I can get more up-to-date statistics ? According to the documentation

> autovacuum_analyze_threshold
>
> Specifies the minimum number of inserted, updated or deleted tuples
> needed to trigger an ANALYZE in any one table. The default is 50
> tuples. This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or
> on the server command line; but the setting can be overridden for
> individual tables by changing table storage parameters.

- Does it mean that either deletes, updates or inserts gets to 50 triggers an auto analyze ? Because I am not seeing this behaviour.
- If I change the values for the tables, should I do the same for their indexes ? Is there any option like cascade or similar that changing the table makes the values also affect the corresponding indexes ?

Thank you in advance for any advice. If you need any further details, let me know.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-autovacuum.html